# Can $0\le\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^tf(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau\le a$ imply $\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^tf(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$ exists?

Tags: limits

Suppose $f(t)\in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $t$. If
$$0\le\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^tf(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau\le a$$
where $a$ is a positive constant, can we say the limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^tf(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$ exists?

Edit: Or a more meaningful problem is: under what condition does the limit exist?

Comment: Am I not understanding something? To compare the limit with other numbers, first it has to exist, or else the comparison makes no sense.

Comment: @JavierBadia: sometimes we use the problem given above to try to prove the existence of the limit. For a very simple example, we already know the limit of $g(t)$ exists and $0<f(t)<g(t)$. Then we can claim that the limit of $f(t)$ is bounded below by zero and upper by the limit of $g(t)$. Then we can say something of the limit of $f(t)$.

Comment: No, what you can say is that $f(t)$ is bounded; then, if for example you know that $f(t)$ is increasing, then you know that its limit exists and that $\lim\ f(t) \le \lim g(t)$. You can't talk about limits without first knowing if they exist. If (again) I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, your inequality should be $0 \le \int_0^t f(\tau)\ d\tau \le a$.

Comment: @JavierBadia: do you mean I cannot use the limit symbol in the inequality? Then can we change $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^t$ to $\int_0^\infty$? I think we can't, right? because we don't if $\int_0^\infty$ exists. We cannot say $0<\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau<a$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)$ either. Then what is the best and rigorous way to describe the same meaning?

Comment: Since you accepted Clayton's answer, it would seem that $\int_0^t f(\tau)\ d\tau$ is indeed what you mean. The problem isn't the limit symbol; by definition, $\int_0^\infty f = \lim_{t\to \infty} \int_0^t f$. The problem is that by saying that this integral is between $0$ and $a$, you are implicitly assuming that it exists, otherwise you couldn't compare because you can't compare a number with something that doesn't exist. (cont.)

Comment: The issue here is that you ask if from $0 \le \lim \int_0^t f \le a$ we can deduce the limit in question ($\lim \int_0^t f$) exists. But if it turns out it doesn't exist, then the question didn't make sense in the first place.

I'm not sure what the best and rigorous way to describe the same meaning is, because the way I see it, there is no meaning. I hope this doesn't sound rude; I'm just trying to use the mathematical terms. The question as stated has no meaning because you are using something that you don't know exists in a way that can only be used if it in fact exists.

Comment: @JavierBadia: let's put the original problem aside. I put this problem in the following way. If $0\le f\le g$ and $\int_0^\infty g \mathrm{d}\tau=\gamma$ exists, how to prove or is it correct that $\int_0^\infty f\mathrm{d} \tau$ exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't true. Let $t\in\Bbb R^+$. Then $$0\leq\int_0^t \sin(x)\,dx\leq 2,$$ but  $\int_0^t \sin(x)\,dx$ can be seen to alternate (just look at $t=n\pi$), so it can't converge.

An Answer to the Edit: If the integrand is nonnegative, then the integral becomes a monotonically increasing sequence bounded above; therefore, the limit exists.

Comment: I encountered this problem while reading a paper published in a top journal. The authors of the paper just conclude the existence of the limit naturally. I wonder if I miss something. Or a more meaningful problem might be: under what condition does the limit exist?

Comment: An easy and probably not-very-general condition is that the integrand be nonnegative. Then the integral is a monotonically increasing sequence bounded above, so must converge. My counterexample works because of cancellation.

Comment: Got it!!! I missed the positiveness of the function $f(t)$.

Comment: Glad I could help; please don't forget to accept the answer (and upvote) if you have found it helpful and what you wanted.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot.